# How to use the output from a function of a module in another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have a mdoule, where i create a db connection and a function which runs a query.
I want to use the output of this query in another module. How do I do this?

The query is supposed to return the value from the key-value pair (hello:world).
However, everytime I try to use the variable in another module, I end up with "true" instead of "world".

my code is here
https://github.com/rishavs/RedisDbConnect

I want to call the getValue function from app.js and maybe console.log(db.getValue()) the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return value from async function like from sync. You need to use callback way. Modify your code like this:

getValue function:

```
var getValue = function(cb) {
    dbConnection.get("hello", function (err, reply) {
        var val = reply ? reply.toString() : null;
        cb(err, val);
    });
};
```

Controller:

```
app.get('/json', function(req, res, next) {
    res.contentType('application/json');
    db.getValue(function(err, val) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(val);  
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks. I was trying to avoid callbacks as I am new to coding, but I guess its time for me to get rolling. I will report back if your solution works for me.

Comment: btw,what does this line do?

"var val = reply ? reply.toString() : null;"

i suspect the "?" is an OR. what about the " : null;" part?
is it "return reply if reply.toString is null"?

Comment: This is short equivalent for `var val; if (reply) { val = reply.toString(); } else { val = null };` It needed here to prevent error when reply returned as `null` or `undefined`.